# OSX: Add Dock icon for dedicated Terminal command

Tags: macos, command-line, dock, mutt

I use Mutt. I want a dock icon to launch it. Is such a thing possible?

I'm looking for a way to add a second Terminal icon to the Dock which lets me launch a specific command, "mutt" in this instance.

I want to group this icon with the other app icons, ie I'd rather not drop a .command file into the right-hand "documents" section of the dock.

Comment: AFAICT Platypus is not a suitable solution, as it runs scripts (not executables) and displays output in a dialog window (not an interactive console).

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281372/executing-shell-scripts-from-the-os-x-dock

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open `/Applications/Utilities/AppleScript Editor` and enter the following:

```
tell application "Terminal" to do script "mutt"
```

Save as application anywhere you want, then drag from there to the Dock.

---

You might need to specify mutt's absolute path. You get that from Terminal by entering

```
which mutt
```

Answer (score 6):

Use Applescript (or Automator). Fire up Script Editor:

```
do shell script "mutt"
```

Save it as an Application, and drop it on your dock as needed.  You can set the icon to whatever via the usual way (info pane, paste (cmd-v) in an image after selecting the current icon).

Comment: You don't have a terminal (tty) doing it like this. Mutt assumes non-interactive session and complains that `No recipients were specified`.

Comment: Ah, fair enough.  Seems in my fatigue I didn't bother to try it and see what Mutt did.  Good counter-answer

Answer (score 3):

You could write an AppleScript:

```
do shell script "mutt"
```

Save as an Application and drop it on your Dock. You can also change the icon, just copy an image, select your app, go to the info pane (command-i), click on the little icon at the top, and paste your image (command-v).

Comment: whoops - @peelman beat me to it... Didn't notice...